# Android Studio: Closing WebView causes other buttons to lose functionality

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new to Android Studio (and generally Java) programming.
I have written a program which uses a button called `button_open_html` to open WebView in full screen and show a local html file; I added a back button. I also have a button `btn1` which shows shows some text on-screen when it's pressed. Before launching WebView, `btn1` works well. After I open and close WebView though, it loses its functionality. On the other hand, the html button's functionality is still there. Here is the code in the MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapp1;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String lastButtonName;
    private String[][] buttonHtmlArray;

    private static final String TAG = "Museums";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Add button functionality for btn1
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);   // call button by ID so we can do stuff w/ it
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "TEXT");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MORE TEXT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        // Create a 2D array to store button names and HTML file names
        buttonHtmlArray = new String[][]{
                {"button_open_html", "html_vsc_2.html"}
        };

        // Loop through the array and set click listeners for each button
        for (String[] buttonHtml : buttonHtmlArray) {
            Button button = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(buttonHtml[0], "id", getPackageName()));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lastButtonName = buttonHtml[0];  // Store the button name
                    openWebView(lastButtonName, buttonHtml[1]);  // Pass the HTML file name
                }
            });
        }

        // Initialize the WebView
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    private void openWebView(String buttonName, String htmlFileName) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + htmlFileName);
        lastButtonName = buttonName;

        Button backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (lastButtonName != null) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Reassign click listeners for the buttons
            for (String[] buttonHtml : buttonHtmlArray) {
                Button button = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(buttonHtml[0], "id", getPackageName()));
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lastButtonName = buttonHtml[0];  // Store the button name
                        openWebView(lastButtonName, buttonHtml[1]);  // Pass the HTML file name
                    }
                });
            }
            lastButtonName = null;
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

When I add more buttons unrelated to WebView, they also lose their functionality. When I add more buttons that open WebView, their functionality is not affected, so it's a "common trend". As a disclaimer, the above is a code constructed with the help of AI, but was heavily modified by me.

The question is: how should I modify this code in order for the non-WebView related buttons to not lose their functionality?